# Execute sbt task before packaging of fat-jar

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I wrote a small `sbt` plugin for some resource files editing in project's `target` directory (actually, it just works similary to `maven` profiles). Now, when I wrote and tested my simple custom sbt task (let's call it `interpolateParameters`), I want it to be executed between resource copying and jar creation when running `sbt assembly`. However, I can't find any documentation about which tasks are executed "under the hood" of `assembly` task provided by sbt-assembly plugin. And actually I doubt is it even possible.

Therefore, I have 2 questions: is it possible to somehow execute my task between `sbt assembly`'s compile + copyResources and "create jar" steps? And if not, is there a way to achieve what I want without creating my own fork of `sbt-assembly` plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with making `assembly` depends on my task `interpolateParameters`, and `interpolateParameters` depends on `products`. Here is part of my resulting build.sbt file with solution:

```scala
lazy val some<oduleForFatJar = (project in file("some/path"))
  .dependsOn(
    someOtherModule % "test->test;compile->compile"
  )
  .settings(
    name := "some module name",
    sharedSettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= warehouseDependencies,
    mainClass in assembly := Some("com.xxxx.yyyy.Zzzz"),
    assemblyJarName in assembly := s"some_module-${version.value}.jar",
    assembly := {
      assembly dependsOn(interpolateParameters) value
    },
    interpolateParameters := {
      interpolateParameters dependsOn(products) value
    },
    (test in assembly) := {}
  )
```

Hope it can help someone.